# Create nodes in SKS file vs Programmatically

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am currently trying to increase my frame rate and was wondering if it was better to create sprites in the sks file manually or to create them programmatically? Additionally is it faster to load an image or create an SKSprite node programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're talking about creating single sprites, then it won't make any difference - the time taken to unarchive and initiate the .sks file with its included SKSpriteNodes compared to allocating a few in code in `viewDidLoad` will be insignificant, and even if it were, you'd only see a slight hesitation at the start of the program - probably before anything appeared on screen.

The question about loading images is really the same question - you either created your textured SKSPriteNodes in the .sks file or create them in code with `let mySprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "myImage")`

Unless you have a loop, creating 10s or 100s or sprites with every `update()`, I'd look elsewhere for your framerate problems:

- How many sprites do you have in your scene?
- What, if any, physics are
  involved?
- How much code do you run in `update()` against each node?
- Are you seeing poor frame rates in the simulator or on an actual
  device? If it's in the simulator, what model of Mac is this on?

Add the following to your Gameviewcontroller:

```
skView.showsFPS = true    
skView.showsNodeCount = true
skView.showsDrawCount = true    // show how many draw passes are required
skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true   // Render sprites more efficiently
```

the first 3 will help diagnose problems and the 4th will improve performance.

Comment: how about an SKShape node vs a sprite node with images

Comment: @joshLor - according to Apple https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skshapenode *However, the SKSprite​Node class offers higher performance than this class, so use shape nodes sparingly.* So if you have frame rate problems using sprites, moving to shapes will make things worse.

Comment: What about shape nodes vs sprites with images. Which is faster?

Comment: Well Apple state that Sprites are faster.

Comment: Even though the image has to be loaded

Comment: Yes - the expensive part is not loading the image but in drawing it - the iOS hardware can draw bitmaps (sprites) faster than it can draw shapes.

Comment: Thanks, I will note that down

Comment: Is it possible to preload the sprite to increased performance?

Comment: Additionally what is faster creating an SKlabel node programmatically or in the SKS file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139932/discussion-between-steve-ives-and-joshlor).